# Как переделать этот код под динамическую память?

Tags: c++

Даны натуральное число n и целочисленная матрица [aij]i,j=1, ... ,n. Получить  b1, b2, ..., bn, где bi – это  max aij    min aji
                               1<=j<=n    1<=j<=n
 Сам код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int max (int a[100][100], int b[100] , int size)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < (size); j++)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < (size); i++)
        {
            int k = 0;
            if (a[k][j] <= a[i][j])
            {
                k = i;

            }
            b[j]  = a[k][j];
        }
    }
    return b[100];
}


int min (int a[100][100], int b[100] , int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (size); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < (size); j++)
        {
            int k = 0;
            if (a[i][k] >= a[i][j])
            {
                k = j;

            }
            b[i]  = a[i][k];
        }
    }
    return b[100];
}


int main()
{
    int n;
    int array[100][100];
    int  maxi[100];
    int mini[100];
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
            cin >> array[i][j]; // ввели массив

        //cout <<"   "<<  endl;
    }

//функция ищущая максимум в столбце (записывает значения в новый массив)

max (array, maxi, n);

//функция ищущая минимум в строке (записывает значения в новый массив)

min (array, mini, n);

//вывод массивов поочередности



    for (int u = 0; u < n; u++)
        cout <<" B." << u + 1 <<" = " << maxi[u] <<"   "<< mini[u] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, заданные условия трудно понять. В  процессе написания кода я, *кажется, разобрался по комментариям к `min` и `max`,* что требуется.

### Учитывая, что матрица квадратная, то есть `x == y`, находим максимум в каждом столбце и минимум в каждой строке матрицы.

```cpp
#include <iostream>


void max(const int* const* const& matrix, int* const& result, const size_t& n) {
    for (size_t x = 0; x < n; x++) {
        size_t k = 0;

        for (size_t y = 0; y < n; y++)
            if (matrix[y][x] >= matrix[k][x])
                k = y;

        result[x] = matrix[k][x];
    }
}


void min(const int* const* const& matrix, int* const& result, const size_t& n) {
    for (size_t y = 0; y < n; y++) {
        size_t k = 0;

        for (size_t x = 0; x < n; x++)
             if (matrix[y][x] <= matrix[y][k])
                k = x;

        result[y] = matrix[y][k];
    }
}


int main() {
    int** matrix;

    int* max_store;
    int* min_store;

    size_t n;
    std::cin >> n;

    matrix = new int*[n];
    max_store = new int[n];
    min_store = new int[n];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        matrix[i] = new int[n];

        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
            std::cin >> matrix[i][j]; // ввели массив
    }

    max(matrix, max_store, n);
    min(matrix, min_store, n);

    for (size_t iteration = 0; iteration < n; iteration++)
        std::cout << "B." << iteration << ": " << max_store[iteration] << " " << min_store[iteration] << std::endl;
}
```

На вводе ожидается что-то в виде:

```
3
4 3 2
7 1 23
9 10 11
```

На выходе получится:

```
B.1: 9 2
B.2: 10 1
B.3: 23 9
```